# Why the constructor of std::ostream is protected?

Tags: c++, iostream, ostream

Why I can't just create an "empty" stream for my output like this

```
std::ostream out;
```

?

This rows is apparently illegal with both `clang 3.4` and `gcc 4.8.1` under linux with `libstdc++`, I really don't get why, I mean why I can't just create a stream out of nowhere and use it like I want to ? notice that `std::ofstream out;` is 100% ok instead. I just don't get the logic behind this.
This is even stranger if you consider that after the creation I can just use this buffer and share a common buffer with other buffers with `copyfmt` so there is no real need for my `std::ostream` to be initialized to something right from the creation of the object to be useful.

Please don't deviate from this, I don't need `stringstreams`, I need `ios` streams because of what I have to do and because of the methods and the properties that they are offering.

Comment: What do you expect `ostream` to do?

Comment: @Rapptz behave like `std::cout` or `std::cerr` ? be just like a stream for the output ?

Comment: I think he means "output to where". BTW - cout and cerr output to different locations. They just happen to be locations that by default print to the screen

Comment: @cluracan and what this location is ? I just don't care about the location, I need a stream for generic output

Comment: cerr prints to the "standard error stream". That stream can be intercepted and move to, e.g., a log file (even after compilation - you can do it when you run a program). cout prints to the "standard output stream". This too can be intercepted and moved to a file, or to be the input of another program etc. If you want to write to standard output, use cout. if you want to write to standard error stream, use cerr. If you want to write somewhere else, you need to first decide where that "somewhere else" is. **tl;dr** - use cout.

Comment: @cluracan in my view I need more than 1 stream because of the different kind of informations that I would like to output, I'm also seeing `std::cout` more like "the terminal" than a stream, If I just output everything to std::cout or std::cerr, than I have nothing left to analyze and everything is scattered in 2 buffers

Comment: cout isn't the terminal. It's just the terminal unless the caller of your program (NOT YOU) decides otherwise. If you had two different ostreams writing to the same place (say, the terminal), they'd interfere with each other. It's like having two `int`s with the same address, that you use separately! No one would be able to trust a stream if some other part of the program could write to the exact same place whenever it wants.

Comment: @user2485710: You can create an `std::ostream` if you want to but you can't use the default construct. You'd need to pass in a pointer to a stream buffer (`std::streambuf*`) which can be null. For the streams to do anything, they need a stream buffer, however, which deals with sending the characters somewhere, e.g., a `std::filebuf` sends them to a file, a `std::stringbuf` sends them to a string, and user-defined stream buffers can send them wherever you wants them to send characters to, e.g., a GUI window or some area in memory.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'll admit that I don't understand it either.  I can't find any
default constructor at all for `std::istream`, and I would think
you would want one if you want to create a bidirectional stream,
because of the strange way `std::ios_base` works: the
constructor does *not* initialize anything, but the derived
class must call `std::ios_base::init` explicitly in its
constructor.  When multiple inheritance is involved (i.e.
bidirectional IO, where the class derives from both 
`std::istream` and `std::ostream`), I would expect only the most
derived class to call `std::ios_base::init`.  (In
`std::iostream`, `std::ios_base::init` will be called twice.)
In fact, before looking it up in the standard, I was about to
answer that the default constructor was protected, because it
didn't call `std::ios_base::init`, and using it directly, rather
than in a derived class, would result in an uninitialized
stream.

Anyhow, your immediate problem has a simple solution:

```
std::ostream out( NULL );
```

Also: the function you need to set up its sink later is the
non-const version of `rdbuf()`, not `copyfmt()`.  `rdbuf()` is
used to read and to set the pointer to the `streambuf`,
`copyfmt()` copies the formatting flags, but does *not* touch
the pointer to `streambuf`.

So you can do things like:

```
std::ostream out( NULL );
//  ...
std::filebuf fileBuffer;
if ( filenameGiven ) {
    fileBuffer.open( filename.c_str(), std::ios_base::out );
}
if ( fileIsOpen() ) {
    out.rdbuf( &fileBuffer );
} else {
    out.rdbuf( std::cout.rdbuf() );
}
```

(I do this a lot.  In fact, I thought that it was the usual 
idiom when you didn't know up front whether to output to a file
or to `std::cout`.)

EDIT:

And yet another correction: the non-const version of `rdbuf` calls `clear()`,
so you don't have to.  (I knew I'd done this without calling `clear()`, but
when I saw that `init` set `badbit`...)

Anyhow: the summary is: it's usually preferrable to pass a pointer to a valid
streambuf to the constructor of `std::ostream`, but if you can't, it's
perfectly valid to pass a null pointer, and set a valid pointer later using
`rdbuf()`.  And the answers which say otherwise are simply wrong.

Comment: finally :D . men the ios part of the standard library is a real journey for a programmer ...

Comment: The funny initialization dance happens between `std::ios` and `std::istream`/`std::ostream`/`std::iostream`: users don't have to deal with it unless they want to directly derive from `std::ios`! The reason that dance is done is to avoid the stream buffer to be set twice when constructing an `std::iostream`: `std::ios::init()` is just called from that class's default constructor. ... and that is actually also the reason for the default construct of `std::ostream` being protected: it doesn't touch the stream buffer in `std::ios` and leaves it uninitialized!

Comment: @user2485710 It's actually a lot simpler than much of the rest of the standard library.  From a user's point of view, of course, it's complicated, because it is doing a very complicated job.

Comment: @DietmarKühl That's what I thought to begin with.  I can't find _any_ default ctor for `std::istream` in C++11; the constructor of`std::iostream` is specified as calling both `std::istream` and `std::ostream` with the streambuf pointer (which _will_ result in `std::ios::init()` being called twice).  Can it be that we are both thinking of classical iostream?

Comment: @JamesKanze: You are right. ... and there is also no default constructor in C++2003 (I don't have a version of C++1998 to check there). That's weird although there shouldn't be too much of an issue as the stream buffer needs to be initialized eventually and it seems just to be mandated to be done through the `std::istream` branch.

Answer (score 10):

`std::ostream` is conceptually abstract - you're not supposed to create them (but see other answers for more detail on that).

`std::stringstream` gives you everything `std::ostream` does because it derives from it. This also means that anywhere you want an `std::ostream&`, for example in function arguments, you can pass a `std::stringstream` object.

You say "there's no need for [it] to be initialised [...] to be useful". That makes no sense at all. You cannot use *anything* that hasn't been initialised: even `int`s.

Comment: I forgot to specify that from my viewpoint an initialization to a particular value or state given from the user can be useless, that's what I meant with that words; but anyway, where I can find the hierarchy of ostream ?

Comment: please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18031357/why-the-constructor-of-stdostream-is-protected#comment26376038_18031398

Comment: `std::ostream` isn't abstract at all! It doesn't even have any `virtual` functions except it destructor. You can create an `std::ostream` by using the constructor which takes an `std::streambuf*`.

Comment: Alright, notionally abstract, rather than explicitly abstract. I'd argue the CTR that takes a streambuf is a factory.... :)

Comment: @SteveL You'd argue wrong.  It's perfectly correct, and actually quite frequent (at least in my work) to use instances of `std::ostream`.  In fact, the classes which derive from `std::ostream` are only there for convenience; fundamentally, the only class you need is `std::ostream`.  (And I don't understand where you see a factory.  The constructor of `std::ostream` doesn't call `new`, ever.)

Comment: @JamesKanze - OK that's interesting, because I figured `basic_ostream`  and `basic_istream` themselves as convenience "wrapper" classes over the facilities of `ios` and `ios_base` - and `streambuf`. On the factory front, what I meant was that the `streambuf` is the *actual* stream, and `ostream` an API over it (in essence - I know there's more to it than that). So, factory with a small 'f' :)

Comment: @user2485710 - hierarchy of `ostream` - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/

Comment: @SteveL `basic_ostream` and `basic_istream` have real behavior: formatting and parsing.  `ios_base` doesn't really; it just provides some simple common functionality.  And `streambuf` really defines a separate hierarchy, with its own behavior, used by `basic_istream` and `basic_ostream` (but there's nothing to prevent you from using it otherwise.

Answer (score 8):

The **default** constructor of `std::basic_ostream` is `protected` because it generally doesn't make any sense to create an `std::basic_ostream` without setting its `std::basic_streambuf` and the default constructor actually doesn't do any initialization (see below). There is, however, another constructor taking a stream buffer as argument. If you really need an `std::ostream` which isn't set up to do anything, yet, you can use that constructor:

```
std::ostream out(0);
```

This `std::ostream` will have the `std::ios_base::badbit` set until a stream buffer is set up using `std::ios::rdbuf()`.

The underlying reason for `std::ostream`'s default constructor being `protected` is that it actually deliberately doesn't do anything useful! In particular, calling this constructor [from a further derived class] will **not** initialize the stream buffer at all: the standard doesn't mandate any behavior explicitly, i.e., the default constructor has implicitly the behavior of the generate default constructor (or, in C++2011 as if it is defined using `= default`). To get the stream buffer initialized, it would need to call `std::ios::init()`. The reason for this odd behavior is that constructing an object of the further derived class `std::iostream` would initialized the `std::ios` object twice, once through `std::ostream` and once through `std::istream`.

Unlike some of the other answers suggest, `std::ostream` isn't abstract at all. In fact, it only has exactly one `virtual` function anyway and that is its destructor (the destructor being `virtual` happens to be my fault; I'm not entirely convinced that it was really a good idea to force that).

Comment: I think you misworded something.  What does it mean to say "The default constructor is _abstract_"?  Functions aren't abstract, classes are, and constructors can't be virtual either.  The default constructor simply isn't there (and since there are other constructors, the compiler won't generate it either).

Comment: @JamesKanze: good point. I meant to write *protected* (will correct in a moment). Thanks!

Comment: You're post is exactly what I thought, until I looked it up in the standard.  There _is_ no default constructor, at least that I can find.  What you describe makes better sense than what is in the standard (and it is what I thought too, until I looked it up), but it doesn't seem to be the case.  (Maybe it was the case with classical, pre-standard IO stream, and we're both thinking of this.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: Awkward but you're right! There isn't even a `protected` default constructor. That means that standard libraries will have an extra constructor which users can't use (i.e., it takes a type users can't name) and which doesn't do anything. Still things to learn (or relearn more likely) about IOStreams! ;)

Comment: thanks for your contribute too, it's always nice to read something in the details. I will probably join comp.lang.c++ soon :D

Answer (score 3):

The std::ostream is a generalized stream class. Because of that it has no way of knowing what it is streaming to, which is the whole point of having a generalized class.

When you send data to a stream it doesn't actually store the data itself. It simply passes it forward to an associated buffer. Taking this into consideration, creating a generalized stream without assigning this buffer to it makes no sense, as the generalized class cannot create an empty generalized buffer. (The buffer itself needs to be a buffer of a concrete type, which is also understood by looking at the generalized buffer std::treambuf that doesn't have a public consstructor at all)

Compare this with the std::ofstream, which is a stream with a specific type of buffer, it is now possible for the ofstream to know what kind of buffer it uses, thus being able to instantiate a default std::filebuf.

To solve your concrete problem.

Create the buffer of your wanted type first, and then create the a generalized std::ostream with the buffer as a parameter. You can then at a later point connect to a file using std::filebuf::open().

Example:

```
std::filebuf fileBuffer;
std::ostream myOstream(&fileBuffer); // Hand over the address of the fileBuffer

fileBuffer.open("filename.txt", std::ios::out);
myOstream << "Text to file";
```

Comment: His whole point was that he didn't have the `streambuf` until later, so he couldn't do this.  That may be a questionable architecture; the `streambuf` usually needs a lifetime at least as long as that of the `istream`, so one would expect it to be created first, but there are certainly exceptions to this rule.

Answer (score 2):

`stringstream` is an `ios` stream.

But about your question:

An `ostream` writes somewhere. if you declare

```
std::ostream out;
out << "Hello, world!"<<std::endl
```

the `"Hello, world!"` should be written somewhere. But where? That depends on the implementation for each specific `ostream`. Yes, there is a buffer, but that buffer also depends on the specific implementation.

So when you say "I want an `ostream`" I have to ask - one which writes stuff... to where?

Given your answer, that will tell me which specific instance/implementation of `ostream` you need to use.

Comment: Well, if I write `int a;` I don't have to declare where to store the int, the compiler does for me, why a stream can't have a "default" "fallback" value and still be in a valid state ?

Comment: Because it has to print somewhere! And where will it print? If there was a default, it would be "I don't know where to print to, so I'll just throw away everything you write". That is the equivalent to your `int` example (if you could only write to an `int` and not read from it, like `ostream`). But that behaviour would be silly and most likely not what you want. Just tell us what you want to actually happen when you write something, and why cout isn't good enough

Comment: scenario: I have a program written in C++ that also offers a wrapper to a scripting language, I need to store and output ( have a buffer basically ) about the state of the application, the errors and the debug messages, but I want to keep this 3 buffers separated for the C++ applications and the scripting wrapper, so I need a total of 6 buffers and I don't want them to be mixed together, I want them to never see one to another and I want to decide on what output I can redirect those 6 streams: what class or type you pick for that ?

Comment: Then have your class (?) receive and remember a POINTER (or reference) to an `ostream` where it will output whatever. Then when creating this class you can decide if you want to give it `cout` (to output to the "standard output", or `ostringstream` to use internally later, or `ofstream` to write to a file. You keep not saying WHERE you want the output to go! If you want the screen, you use `cout`. If you want the screen, but want to also "keep them separated" then explain what that means...

Comment: if i create a `stringstream` I don't have to make this kind of choices, why is that so hard for this part of the library to just create an object, let the object grow as the content is being inserted in the stream and let the user decide at some point in the code where to output stuff; why I need to set this kind of things upfront ? By the way my possible options are `cout`,`cerr`,`clog` and a file .

Comment: What? If you made a `stringstream` you DID make the choice! a `stringstream` IS A STREAM that writes to a string (memory). You decided you wanted to write to memory (not file, not "screen"). You decided. You probably don't realize this, but `ostringstream` **is an ostream**. If this is what you want (writing to memory) use `ostringstream`.

Comment: OK, so where does `clog` write to? a log file? so it's a file too? or somewhere else?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34750/discussion-between-cluracan-and-user2485710)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't chat right now, but in the end let's say that yes, I need clog to write to a file or to the standard output, what is the flexible solution in this case ?

Comment: have clog be a reference (or pointer) to an ostream, and use either cout or ofstream to initialize it.

Comment: @cluracan This answer is simply wrong.  The `streambuf` pointer doesn't have to point anywhere; you can pass `std::istream` a null pointer, and set the `streambuf` later, using `std::istream::rdbuf()`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18031703/2485710 this was what I wanted ... that's what I meant with an empty/default construction and the ability to pick a file or an std::cout based on my wishes.