# making object of istream class, and taking input

Tags: c++, iostream, istream

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 istream A;
 int a;
 A>>a;
}
```

here i am making object of istream class, to take input. but the compiler shows error which I can't understand. Please help me with it...

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Car
{
 private:
    string name;
    string model;
    int engine;
    public:
    friend istream& operator>>(istream&, Car&);     
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, Car);      
};istream& operator>>(istream &d, Car &e) {
    d>>e.name>>e.model>>e.engine;              
    return d;
}ostream& operator<<(ostream &d, Car e)      
{
    d<<e.name<<" "<<e.model<<" "<<e.engine;
    return d;
}
int main()
{
    Car a;
    Car b;
    cout<<"enter car credentials";
    cin>>a>>b;                        
    cout<<a<<b;
}
```

i want to overload the extraction and insertion operators >> << by myself, in my class. so here I have to make references of istream and ostream. so I want to know why I can't make objects of them. I'll add the complete code.. –

Comment: Take input from *what*? File? Console? String?

Comment: what i understand is this that istream is a class. and cin is a predefined object of this class. in istream class there is a function defined as operator>>. now if I make an object of istream class(here i made object A of istream class) then that object will access its member function operator>>. so I should be able to take input using this object too.                           IF I HAVE MISTAKENLY UNDERSTOOD ANYTHING THEN PLEASE CLARIFY ME

Comment: taking input from keyboard

Comment: You misunderstood. `std::istream` can take input from various places, like files (`ifstream`), console (`cin`), or any generic memory. Your `istream` object takes input from nowhere

Comment: related: [Why is the construction of istreams is forbidden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59118913/why-is-the-construction-of-istreams-is-forbidden) / [Why the constructor of std::ostream is protected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18031357/why-the-constructor-of-stdostream-is-protected)

Comment: "_ want to overload the extraction and insertion operators >> << by myself, in my class. so here I have to make references of istream and ostream_" = correct. "_so I want to know why I can't make objects of them_" = does not compute. You have to justify _why_ you want to make objects of them, when the stdlib provides ready-made ones for all common purposes

Answer (score 3):

`std::istream` is a bit of an abstraction (although it's not an abstract class). It wraps some underlying memory buffer and exposes convenient methods to extract data from that buffer.

What is important is that it needs a buffer from which it can extract data. You must provide such buffer to create `std::istream` object, and creating such buffer manually is rather difficult.
This is why no one uses `std::istream` directly, but rather we use `std::cin` for reading input from console, `std::ifstream` for reading from files and `std::istringstream` for reading from strings.

You could extract underlying buffer from `std::cin` to initialize another `std::istream` ([see it online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ibjf8QrZletYQZiD))

```
int main()
{
    std::istream is {std::cin.rdbuf()};
    int a;
    is >> a;
    std::cout << a;
}
```

It is probably possible to avoid using `std::cin` and initialize it directly from [`stdin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/std_streams) (the object that represents resource provided by the operating system), but I have no idea how do that.

Comment: your answer contains so many difficult words for me to understand. i have not yet studied abstract class, buffers... i don't understand these and also can you please explain what is the meaning of using namespace std; i read it at some places but i don't understand clear.

Comment: @AnshulPareek The takeaway from my answer should be "don't go against the language, use `std::cin` or other ready classes". It is possible to create `std::istream` directly, but it doesn't make sense, unless you are working on some library to read from something completely new and previously unknown or you need to deal with a very strange operating system.

Comment: @AnshulPareek Regarding `using namespace std;`, you'd first need to understand concept of namespaces in C++. In general, everything from the standard library lives in namespace `std`, so it will not mix with your own code. If you add `using namespace std;` to your code, all the names (and there are thousands of them) spill into your code, and compiler will get confused which name do you mean (do you want `sort()` from `std` or your own `sort`?). `using namespace std;` is generally considered [a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721) because of those hard to detect and fix errors.

Comment: i want to overload the extraction and insertion operators >> << by myself, in my class. so here I have to make references of istream and ostream. so I want to know why I can't make objects of them. I'll add the complete code..

Answer (score 0):

Use the `std::cin` instance:

```cpp
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    int a;
    std::cin >> a;
}
```

Reference here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin

Comment: why can't i make an object of istream or ostream class??

Comment: @AnshulPareek Why would you want/need to, when `std::cin` already exists and is tied to the correct stream?